# how we can check this integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2{\rm d}x$ converges?

Tags: calculus

This is home work problem, Please Help me How can I check the convergence of the integral  $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2{\rm d}x$$

Comment: The function is very well-behaved near $0$.

Comment: Perhaps you could show that the value of the function is less than 1 everywhere in (0,1).  Would that help?

Comment: Well if you can show that the integral of sinx/x converges, surely the square of a finite value is also a finite value?

Comment: @Kainui That reasoning only works if it was the integral itself that was being squared.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is well defined on any interval $(a,1)$ for $0<a<1$, so the question is, does it get freaky as $a\to 0^+$.

It is well-known (and easy to prove) that for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$,

$$\sin x < x < \tan x$$

And so

$$(\cos x)^2< \left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 < 1 $$

Giving,

$$ \int_0^1(\cos x)^2 dx < \lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^1 \left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 dx < 1 $$

This shows that the integral has a value in $\left(\dfrac{1}{4}(2+\sin(2)), 1\right)$